# Giving Gift to Mourning Spouse?

Tags: halacha, minhag, mourning-aveilus, gifts

Although the Rema (YD 385:3) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.385.3?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ואסור לשלוח מנות לאבל על אביו ואמו כל י"ב חדש - It is forbidden to
>   send [or bring] gifts to one who is in mourning for his father or
>   mother, throughout the twelve months [of mourning]

Is it permitted to give a gift to one's spouse who is in 12 months mourning for a parent? (Does it make a difference whether the gift is a siddur or if it's before Yom Tov?)

(Of course CYLOR - I just wanted to know what the poskim say as there seems to be *[some](http://dinonline.org/2012/07/15/gifts-in-aveilus/)* wiggle room for spouses)